# Expo Android Build Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a React Native app using Expo and have encountered an issue with the Android build process. The app runs smoothly using Expo Go, but I'm facing problems when trying to build the Android APK.

When I attempt to build the Android APK using both Expo CLI and EAS CLI, I encounter the following error: "Request failed with status code 404." As a result, the app closes automatically after running for a few seconds.

I've tried several troubleshooting steps based on online advice, including updating dependencies, reviewing my project configuration, and trying different build commands. However, the issue persists.

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "GreenApp",
    "slug": "GreenApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.anandasok.GreenApp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "f7cec193-dafc-44cf-9ab9-2ced15e7786b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve the "Request failed with status code 404" error during the Android build process. If there are alternative methods to build the Android APK using Expo or suggestions for debugging this issue, I'd greatly appreciate any guidance.

expo build:android has been superseded by eas build. Learn more.

Run the following:

› npm install -g eas-cli
› eas build -p android

expo build:android has been discontinued (January 4, 2023).

```
Request failed with status code 404
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
sougandh@pc-4:~/Desktop/New Folder/GreenApp$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

Use this and you can directly build it on your expo server and download the apk from there